# if-then-else construction in complex stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am relatively new to sql queries and I was wondering how to create a complex stored procedure. My database runs on SQL server.

I have a table customer (id, name) and a table customer_events (id, customer_id, timestamp, action_type). I want add a calculated field customer_status to table customer which is

- 0: (if there is no event for this customer in customer_events) or (the most recent event is > 5 minutes ago)
- 1: if the most recent event is < 5 minutes ago and action_type=0
- 2: if the most recent event is < 5 minutes ago and action_type=1

Can I use if-then-else constructions or should I solve this challenge differently?

Comment: `IF..THEN` is very procedural, whereas (most of the time) sql is set-based. What you actually want is a `CASE` statement. When you say you want a "calculated field on customer table" is it *really* an actual calculated field you want, or do you want to add this field to a select query against the customer table?

Comment: oke, thanks. I want to add this field to a select query against customer table. How could I achieve this?

Comment: If you want to add it to the table, you need a job that runs periodically, if you need it added as part if a result set, you just calculate it within the selct statement (using a left join and a case statement).

Comment: @jmoreno not necessarily - calculated fields are a thing. I just sumised that the OP wanted a field in their select.

Comment: @Jamiec: calculated fields are a thing, calculated fields that get updated 5 minutes after an update or insert in another table are not a thing.

Comment: @jmoreno might be mistaken, but could you not aggregate the definition for the calculated field in the same way we're implying you can for a `case` statement?

Comment: @Jamiec: yes and no.  I was thinking that he wanted a persisted calculated field, which are updated when the row containing the field is inserted or updated.  A non persisted field can be used in the way you describe. But non-persisted fields don't really offer any benefit over a more complex query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in comments, you actually want to add a field to a select query, and in a general sense what you want is a [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement. They work like this:

```
SELECT field1, 
       field2,
       CASE
         WHEN some_condition THEN some_result
         WHEN another_condition THEN another_result
      END AS field_alias
FROM table
```

Applied to your specific scenario, well it's not totally straightforward. You're certainly going to need to `left join` your status table, you also want to aggregate to find the most recent event, along with that event's  action type. Once you have that information, the case statement is straightforward.

Always hard to write sql without access to your data, but something like:

```
SELECT c.id, 
       c.name,
       CASE 
          WHEN e.id IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(minute,e.timestamp,getDate())>=5 THEN 0
          WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,e.timestamp,getDate())<5 AND s.action_type=1 THEN 1
          WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,e.timestamp,getDate())<5 AND s.action_type=0 THEN 2
       END as customer_status
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, client_id, action_type, 
           rank() OVER(partition by client_id order by timestamp desc) AS r
    FROM customer_events
) e
ON c.id=e.client_id AND e.r=1
```

The core of this is the subquery in the middle, it's using a `rank` funtion to give a number to each status by `client_id` ordered by the timestamp descending. Therefore every record with a rank of `1` will be the most recent (for that client). Thereafter, you simply join it on to the client table, and use it to determine the right value for `customer_status`

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you get the event info into "Most_Recent_Event_Mins_Ago".  If none it will be NULL.

```
SELECT Id, Name,
       CASE 
          WHEN Most_Recent_Event_Mins_Ago IS NULL THEN 0
          WHEN Most_Recent_Event_Mins_Ago <5 AND Action_type = 0 THEN 1
          WHEN Most_Recent_Event_Mins_Ago <5 AND Action_type = 1 THEN 0
          ..other scenarions
          ELSE yourDefaultValueForStatus
       END as Status
FROM customer
WHERE
...
...
```